# Standard delegate pattern seems at odds with delegate purpose

Tags: objective-c, design-patterns, delegates

If I follow any of a number of examples available on the web, I see a common theme emerge with the delegate pattern:

```
myClass.delegate = self;
```

From what I read, delegation is *supposed* to uncouple behavior, but allow interaction between classes, however, only assigning a single delegate seems to be 100% at odds with this behavior.

I have a web dev background, and I am intimately familiar with pub/sub patterns, but what I'm trying to wrap my head around is why I would only allow a single delegate (`self`) to be able to act on whatever happens in `myClass`. That would seem to ruin the entire point of delegation.

Maybe I'm misunderstanding something, or maybe this is only the simplest form of delegation, but could someone please explain how statically assigning (in the classic sense) one class to another's delegate decouples behavior in any meaningful way.

Bonus: Perhaps a way to allow multiple classes to act on a delegation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The delegate asserts additional control over the delegated class. The most simple example is `windowShouldClose:` method in the NSWindowDelegate protocol. The class delegate gets a chance to **proactively** override closing the window in NSWindow. **If multiple delegates were allowed, multiple delegates could supply conflicting orders which would be an undesirable result.**

[image]

Delegation allows you to customize behavior without subclassing. Because a class can implement many delegate protocols, it is a key part of the MVC programming model in Objective-C. *Delegation allows you to create one class as a "Controller" of multiple other classes.*

For acting **reactively** to what happens to the class, you use a pub/sub model of key value observing. For example, `NSOperationQueue` has an observable property `operationCount` to let you react to changes in the number of operations in the queue.

Comment: +1 for the first time I've even heard the phrase "key value observing". Thanks so much for clearly explaining. It seems I misunderstood the underlying purpose of delegation.

Answer (score 1):

It decouples behavior in the sense that the delegator needn't know anything at all about the delegate other than that it (possibly) responds to a certain set of methods. This makes it so that classes that have delegate can be used in entirely different codebases/situation without changes. It's particularly applicable when writing Framework classes that will be used by someone else, which is one reason you see it so much in the system frameworks.

One of the major uses of delegation is to allow customization of an object's behavior without subclassing. Take for example the `NSWindowDelegate` method [`-windowWillResize:toSize:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSWindowDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSWindowDelegate/windowWillResize%3atoSize%3a), where the delegate can return a different size than the suggested one to implement custom sizing behavior. How would this scenario be handled with multiple delegates each returning a different value?

Of course, sometimes delegate methods are merely meant to inform the delegate that some particular event has occurred. In these cases, it is indeed reasonable for multiple objects to want to be notified. This is provided for in Objective-C/Cocoa by notifications ([NSNotification](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html)), and [Key Value Observing](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html) (KVO). You'll find plenty of cases in Cocoa where a delegate method also has a corresponding notification posted in case objects other than the delegate want to know about it (e.g. [windowWillClose:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSWindowDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)/NSWindowWillCloseNotification).

Comment: 100%. One other thought: I often think of delegation as an alternative to the *subclassing* you might do in other languages to, say, change the behaviour of a view. Compared to subclassing, delegation has a much cleaner interface (for both delegator and delegate) than the often-murky interface between a subclass and superclass.

Comment: Yep, that's what I meant by "One of the major uses of delegation is to allow customization...without subclassing", but I didn't explain why that's a good idea. "Often-murky" is definitely a good description of customization through subclassing. Such customization is also easier to break if the superclass is changed down the line, where delegation makes the intended customization points explicit and part of the API.